# Как сравнить даты при помощи шаблонов

Tags: python, django

Делаю сайт при помощи django. Передо мной стала задача сравнить две даты при помощи шаблонов. 
Я передаю в html разметку массив параметров

```
return render(request, "sites.html", {"site": arrsite } )
```

Вывожу таким вот образом

```
 {% if site.count > 0 %}
 {% for person in site %}
 <p>Активен до: {{person.data}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
```

В    `person.data` приходит строка сл. формата `2019-10-12 20:24:56`
. Я пытаюсь сравнить эту строку с текущей датой и если текущая дата больше то вместо  `<p>Активен до: {{person.data}}</p>` вывести `<p>не активно</p>` 
Я выяснил, что существует такая штука как `{% now "jS o\f F" %}` но не очень понимаю как организовать проверку?

Comment: либо написать собственный фильтр, либо во вьюхе сравнивать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался
Я создал собственный фильтр
В папке приложения создал папку с названием templatetags
в нее поместил два файла (**init**.py, test.py)
файл test.py содержит сл код

```
from django import template
import datetime
import time
register = template.Library()
@register.filter(name='cut')
def cut(value):
    ms = int(round(time.time() * 1))
    a=""
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    if ms>time.mktime(dt.timetuple()):
        a="Off"
    else:
        a= value
    return a
```

В html разметке подключаем этот шаблон

```
    {% load test %}

{% if "2019-10-12 20:24:56"|cut == "Off" %}
        <p>Отключено</p>
{% else %}
        <p>Активен до: {{ "2019-10-12 20:24:56"|cut }}</p>
{% endif %}
```